# Electron - How to handle off screen window on multiple monitors?

Tags: javascript, windows, electron, multiple-monitors

So basically I have a browserWindow and if the user moves it to any position on the screen, I store that information and then upon restart put the window back in the position it was closed in. The thing I'm trying to tackle is that what if the user moves the window all the way to the side beyond the screen. Something like this:

[image]

Now I know I could do something like x = 1920 - width_of_app and get the window back on screen after user restarts the app
[image]

The problem is when I have multiple monitors. I can get the dimensions of the displays and to calculate the axis I can do something like display_1_width + display_2_width.

[image]

This way I can still do something max_x - width_of_app but then baam, the user decides to change its primary display and now all of the sudden axis are in negative.

[image]

Now if the user moves the window all they way to the left beyond the screen, I'm confused about how to reset the position so its back on screen because I don't know when I should handle negative axis. When the primary monitor is on left then 0 is the limit but if the primary monitor is on the right then the axis can go way below 0.

so my question is how do I handle situation like that? Does electron provide a way to bring the windows back in view? is there a standard I can follow? Maybe someone can tell me a clever way to get the max and min axis of multiple displays. Thanks in advance! any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: imo its nicer if the app starts centre screen of the current screen the mouse is in (like in mosts window managers), most users brains are in the vicinity of the mouse cursor not the last place they moved it, which could be bottom/right so there is only 1 pixel showing to grab onto left, which might be considered a bug

Answer (score 0):

You could try coding to use absolute value of the axis as it would always result in a positive.  The only drawback to doing so is that that the app's location will always be based on the full width, as there are no negatives in absolute values.

Something similar to x = |maxX - width_of_app|.  In this way, even if the result were negative, the value for X would be positive.